# Size of a file stored at azure file service

Tags: python, azure

My file is stored in the Microsoft Azure file service.

**Question**

How can I get the size of the file?

Comment: import azure library if any first... Start coding!

Comment: What have you tried? Azure File storage attaches as SMB and lets you use normal file I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Python solution that is file specific and returns the exact size:

```
file_properties = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name, directory_name, file_name)
file_size = file_properties.properties.content_length
```

If you want additional information try running:

```
file_properties.__dict__.keys()
file_properties.properties.__dict__.keys()
```

output:

```
dict_keys(['name', 'content', 'properties', 'metadata'])
dict_keys(['last_modified', 'etag', 'content_length', 'content_range', 'content_settings', 'copy', 'server_encrypted', 'smb_properties', 'lease'])
```

remove the .keys() to output the values as well in a dictionary.

**Python SDK Docs:**

**get_file_properties():** https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.file.fileservice.html#azure.storage.file.fileservice.FileService.get_file_properties

**models.File attributes:** https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.file.models.html#azure.storage.file.models.File

**models.FileProperties attributes:** https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.file.models.html#azure.storage.file.models.FileProperties

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below documentation to list the files in a file share through python:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage#list-shares-and-snapshots

You can also see the size of the uploaded file through the Azure Portal and through the PowerShell

Path to check in Portal: Storage accounts> click on the storage account >File service>file share

Using PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-powershell#list-the-files-in-the-directory

Comment: Thank you guys for the respond,

This one works:

file_service.get_share_stats("myShareName")

The only thing it does not return the exact size, it rounded the size up to the nearest gigabyte.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience , you could try to get the size of the file via the following ways.

***Azure Portal:***

Login portal, direct view

[image]

***Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer:***

Login tool, direct view

[image]

Please download tool from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer).

***Python SDK:***

User share status method to get the size of the share.

```
file_service.get_share_stats("myshare")
```

Or you could get the bytes of the file and calculate size.

```
System.out.println("File size in bytes is: " + fileSize);
System.out.println("File size in KB is : " + (double)fileSize/1024);
System.out.println("File size in MB is :" + (double)fileSize/(1024*1024));
```

***Download File :***

Download file to local and check the size of the file.

```
file_service.get_file_to_path('myshare', None, '1.png', 'out.png')
```

You could also refer to the thread: 
[How to get or calculate size of Azure File/Share or Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876642/how-to-get-or-calculate-size-of-azure-file-share-or-service)

Comment: Thank you guys for the respond,

This one works:

file_service.get_share_stats("myShareName")

The only thing it does not return the exact size, it rounded the size up to the nearest gigabyte.

Comment: @Anmar Yes,then you could calculate the size of share via the nearest gigabyte. Or you could view the size of files via portal or Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer tool directly. If you think my answer is useful for you , you could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the respond,

This one works:

file_service.get_share_stats("myShareName")

The only thing it does not return the exact size, it rounded the size up to the nearest gigabyte.